# How can I fix No module named 'src.alphabet' error?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

when I write the line:

```
from src.alphabets import Uniprot21
```

I face the problem:

```
No module named 'src.alphabet'
```

How can I solve It?

I use python 3.7

Comment: There's not really enough information here to give a useful answer; please edit your post to include a [mcve].  My first guess is that your `src` directory is missing an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Your code has `src.alphabets`, but the error message says `src.alphabet` (there's no `s` on the end.)  Which is it?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you created file `src.py` and now `import` loads your file instead of module `src` and it can't find `alphabet` in your file.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question [biopython] and BioPython does include sequence alphabets, but this isn't one of them.  My guess is you want to download the [protein-sequence-embedding-iclr2019 alphabets from GitHub](https://github.com/tbepler/protein-sequence-embedding-iclr2019/blob/master/src/alphabets.py) which includes Uniprot21.